# Using SqlAlchemy with RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have a webscraper running across multiple processors and writing to a sqlite database. Since Sqlite isn't meant to handle concurrent writes, I want to use a queue system that can handle multiple inputs, and only 1 object writing to the database

I went through the RabbitMQ hello world example and getting an error.

My `send.py` file:

```
from models import TestCan
from models import TestJobs

import pika

# init_db()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body=TestCan('Test'))
```

The `models.py` file with `TestCan`:

```
class TestCan(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_can'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())


    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name: %s>' % (self.name)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'TestCan' has no len()
```

What does that mean?

Comment: If you're introducing external dependencies, why not introduce a RDBMS that does this for you automagically? Second: You can't publish python objects directly on RabbitMQ, you'll have to serialize and deserialize as needed.

Comment: pickle.loads & picke.dumps worked! Thanks. Can you put that as an answer so I can market it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't publish python objects directly on RabbitMQ, as the message you publish is a string.

You'll have to serialize and deserialize the object first, either by using `json.dumps` and `json.loads` or the `pickle` module.

However, if you're OK with introducing external dependencies (such as RabbitMQ), using a proper RDBMS is an option, or perhaps better to avoid any external tool at all - making your parent process be responsible for the queue and make your childs signal the result back to the parent in some way.

Comment: That would require a lot of re-writing :-) But this works for now